# Simple mysql query is resulting in 2 rows being submitted

Tags: php

I'm using a pretty simple script. All that I'm essentially trying to accomplish is logging a page_view and the time the page was accessed. I have it working great however when I enter phpmyadmin for every entry inserted I have 2 rows instead of one. Each with a unique primary key(the page view id) and an exactly identical time.

I really cant seem to figure this out even though it seems really simple. I've also scoured everywhere for someone having a similar problem and haven't been able to find it.

Here's the code from the inc file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "streamaccess_log";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `streamaccess_log`.`visit_log` (`view_id`, `view_time`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
$conn->exec($sql);
echo "Added time data";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

I've tried using include_once and using require to include the connection script with the connection to the database however it still ends up with 2 rows per page load in phpmyadmin.

Comment: This code will only insert two rows if it's run twice. Check your access logs to see how many times it got hit. Also if `view_id` is your primary key, don't specify it in the query. It's misleading to deliberately add it as `NULL`.

Comment: `All that I'm essentially trying to accomplish is logging a page_view and the time the page was accessed.` so may be at both time same code run so it creates two entry

Comment: MySQL General Query Log http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/5102/log-files/18052/general-query-log#t=201609210515317695149

Comment: I have enabled the log. Basically it runs 2 of the same sequence. It runs a connect, query and then quit twice in a procedural order. Yet there's only 1 established in the script I've posted above.

Comment: Voodoo I say. Let's blame it on voodoo :p .... But seriously, I have seen this happen with `.htaccess` issues coming in twice. btw dang I didn't get an upvote on my Docs page :(

Comment: Using Nginx, wonder if that could be another area to check? Maybe I'm running 2 versions of mysql that are both running a query? Not even sure if that's feasible.